# Apache Wicket textfield onUpdate

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a text field for user input and as soon as it gets a content, I want to perform a service call.

I have added the OnChangeAjaxBehavior onUpdate() method for that, but it indicates the service call after every character.

My code:

```
getTextField().add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
                                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                                    @Override
                                    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                                        refreshDependingComponents(target);
                                        TemplatePage.refreshFeedback(target, getTextField());
                                        getModelObject().setPeriod(getTextField().getInput());
                                        if (code!= null) {
                                            target.add(code);
                                        }
                                    }
```

How can I do that it only make the update and refresh when the user has already clicked away from the textfield?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For TextField and TextArea form components OnChangeAjaxBehavior uses both `input` and `change` JavaScript events, and this is the reason why it fires Ajax calls for each letter.

You can use `new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change")` instead. It will fire Ajax call **only** on `change` event.

Comment: Thank you!
Everyone, this article helped me a lot, too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982404/how-to-force-wicket-onchange-ajax-events-to-be-triggered-if-fields-fail-valida